# Unable to understand python nested functions

Tags: python, function, nested

Im trying to figure out how this code prints 5 7 as output.
Im unable to understand how this code actually executes.

Code:

```
def outer_function(x):
    def inner_increment(x):
        return x + 2
    y = inner_increment(x)
    print(x,y)
outer_function(5)
```

Output:

```
5 7
```

Comment: This question would be a little more interesting if `inner_increment` was defined as `def inner_increment():` and using `x` from the scope of `outer_function`. As it stands, `inner_increment` is declaring it's own variable `x` which masks the parameter from `outer_function`, using none of the scope from `outer_function`. Because there is no dependency on the scope of `outer_function`, there is no reason that `inner_increment` could not just be defined as another top level function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's so simple. As you know statements run sequentially, so the followings will happen:

1- `inner_increment` will be defined

2- `y = inner_increment(x)` called, so it passes `5` to the `innter_increment` function and get 7 as a result putting in `y` variable.

3- finally it will print `5` and `7` in the output.